# Id and name didn't get rendered for input

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have a button on my page, i.e:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" name="myButton" class="myStyle" value="Click me" />
```

For some reason, the id or name didn't get rendered, therefore all my jQuery selector that selects ID are not working... Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the [html is valid](http://validator.w3.org/)? Ensure there's a doctype (nowadays I recommend `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but that's a personal thing, maybe), and be sure there are no un-closed elements.

Comment: What are you using to render your HTML? ... Can you provide some more details?

Comment: Are you selecting elements after DOM is ready?

Comment: This is what going on: `<input type="button" id="addContactButton" value="Save" />` is rendered as `<button type="submit" class="styled">
Save</button>`, notice that the id is missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely stupid mistake by me and my co-worker! I originally used a partial view, my co-worker then copied the partial view html onto the actual view, removed the ID attribute. Then I've been pulling my hair out for the past day editing the partial view!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you included another javascript on the page and $ no longer is a jquery function. You can try doing `jquery("#myButton")` to see if it works.

Then of course, use firebug to see if there any javascript errors. You can also check to make sure the dom is parsed correctly by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$("#myButton")` to select this element. If that's not working, it's something else in your code that's causing the problem.

Comment: But, as he said in the question, *the* **id** or **name** *didn't get rendered*.

Comment: David: I have no idea what that's even supposed to mean, I just tried to piece together the op's intent based on what I assumed he meant.

Comment: This is what going on: `<input type="button" id="addContactButton" value="Save" />` is rendered as `<button type="submit" class="styled"> Save</button>` , notice that the id is missing when rendered. Thanks.

Comment: Saxman: What is rendering it? How are you trying to render it? What language are you using? How are we supposed to know any of these things?